# How to restrict mailbox access in azure active directory application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am able to read other users email using microft.graph api. Need guidance as how to restrict mailbox access so that users can view its email alone.

I created an azure admin and added 3 users. I registered an app and granted Mail.ReadWrite api permission. I generated a token and was able to read others users email. Need guidance as how mailbox access can be restricted to specific user and particular user can access their own email

Need guidance as how to restrict the users from accessing other users email

Comment: You are saying that you logged as User1, and could read emails for User2?

Comment: yes. I generate access token using grant type as client credential, client id and client secret key. When i access the mail "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/messages i am able to access any users email.

Comment: So, as Allen said in the answer, just dont use client credential flow (and remove the application permission to Mail.ReadWrite). Use the user flow and **delegated permission**.

Answer (score 2):

Client credential allows the app to read all the information that it have access to without a user. It means that anyone who opens the app can see the information. See [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0).

What you need is [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0).
To get an access token, the user is redirected to the Microsoft identity platform `/authorize` endpoint. In the authorization code grant flow, after consent is obtained, Azure AD will return an authorization_code to your app that it can redeem at the Microsoft identity platform `/token` endpoint for an access token.

At last, use this access token to access the emails of the logged in user. You won't see other users' emails.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to restrict my app to access specific user email by creating an application policy. This link helped me to achieve this [Limit mailbox access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) Now I am using client credential to generate app level token and access specific users email.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restrict my app to access specific user email by creating an application policy. This link helped me to achieve this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access Now I am using client credential to generate app level token and access specific users email.